# Assign smaller number to variable in 1 line

Tags: java

Is there a one-liner for this function?

```
int side = width < height ? width : height;
width = side;
height = side;
```

Comment: With absolutely no offense to any of the respondents, who were just answering the question, but I would **not** advise that programmers adopt this practice of sacrificing legibility just to save a few lines of code. Compilers are good at optimization, so let them do their job, and let's focus on making the code comprehendible. And if you had a situation where you did this sort of code optimization, it would be incumbent upon the developer to put in some lines of comments in the code to make the intent clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible:

```
width = height = width < height ? width : height;
```

However it's generally not the convention in Java to assign multiple variables on one line.

Answer (score 5):

```java
width = height = width < height ? width : height;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
width = height = Math.min(width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

height = width = width < height ? width : height;